# Several battery connections independant of each other

Tags: batteries

I'm trying to create a battery bank for dac's, preamp's etc. I've ordered 3 x 15Ah 3.2V lifepo4 batteries which will run in series through a 3S BMS, providing around 9.6V total.

But, I'd like to make 3 or 4 outputs/connections from the BMS, one for the dac, one for the preamp etc. I guess I can just wire all these connections to the 2 output terminals on the BMS.

But can I in any way make sure, that these connections to the same terminals are completely independant? That is, that a large surge on one connection won't effect the voltage on the others?

Comment: Use separate wires back to the battery terminals for each load.  Provide local decoupling capacitance right at the load point. You can't do better than that without a lot more complexity.

Comment: DACs and preamps probably shouldn't be having large surges of current anyway.

Comment: If they are connected together, not really possible to make them truly independent.  Large load will impact all if it's cells are used by others.

Comment: Thanks guys, I should maybe have been more specific, the BMS can deliver 20A continous and each channel will only use up to 1A or something (so its dimensioned much too large), but the whole idea of going this route was to get a very stable voltage. Would you think that some capacitance still would make a difference with these numbers?

Answer (score 1):

The propper aproach is to **add decoupling capacitors** very close to the main devices which use significant energy. This will solve all your headakes which would come from inductance in transmission lines.

If you're not sure and want to go overboard, you can combine higher value electrolitic (100-1000uF) with lower value ceramic(1-10uF). The electrolitic is slower but stores more energy and the ceramic one is much faster to respond.